# Boto3 returns only one instance id after running ec2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Following code runs instances as per given requirement e.g 3, but it create tags, add loadbalancer target group to only one instance also return only one instance ID, and skips the remaining two instances.

I don't understand why, can you help me?

```py
import boto3
import json
import botocore
import os
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

AMI = 'ami-047a51fa27710816e'
INSTANCE_TYPE = 't2.micro'
KEY_NAME = 'mikey'
REGION = 'us-east-1'


client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)
client= boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    instance = client.run_instances(
        ImageId=AMI,
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        KeyName=KEY_NAME,
        MaxCount=3,
        MinCount=3
    )
    
    print ("New instance created:", instance)
    instance_id = instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
    waiter = client.get_waiter('instance_running')
    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[instance_id],
    WaiterConfig={
        'Delay': 15
    })
    print (instance_id)
    
    response_tags = client.create_tags(
    Resources=[
        instance_id,
    ],
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': 'test'
        },
    ]
    )
    print ("Tags added")
    clients=boto3.client('elbv2')

    response_tg = clients.register_targets(
        TargetGroupArn='arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789123:targetgroup/target-demo/c64e6bfc00b4658f',
        Targets=[
           {
            'Id': instance_id
           },
        ]
   )
    return ('Instance created', instance_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `run_instances` call will actually return all instance ids, you're just only processing one of them.

This is where you explicitly only extract a single instance id.

```py
instance_id = instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
```

What you should do is process all of them with something like this:

```py
instance = client.run_instances() # Your full call here
instance_ids = [item['InstanceId'] for item in instance['Instances']]

waiter = client.get_waiter('instance_running')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=instance_ids)

#... now all your instances are running
response_tags = client.create_tags(
    Resources=instance_ids,
    Tags=[{"Key": "Name", "Value": "Test"}]
)

elb_client = boto3.client("elbv2")

response_tg = elb_client.register_targets(
    TargetGroupArn="arn...",
    Targets=[{"Id": instance_id} for instance_id in instance_ids]
)
```

The variable `instance_ids` is now a list with the three instance ids and you'll have to update the `register_targets` and `create_tags` calls as well to reflect this.

Comment: Now lambda function giving invalid syntaxerror on following line      waiter = client.get_waiter('instance_running')

Comment: oops, missed the closing square brackets in the line before that

Comment: `Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter InstanceIds[0], value: ['i-00c3645f4634ca4fe', 'i-0bb45f454fb50ea02'], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>: ParamValidationError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 40, in lambda_handler
    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[instance_ids])`

Comment: now returning two ids but now failing parameter validation

Comment: Please take a closer look at my answer - that's not the code I wrote. As I mentioned you're going to have to update the other API calls as well.

Comment: still parameter validation failed at tag function using same as your answer, i think tag function accepts only string value